# Applying javascript to a textbox unobtrusively

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, unobtrusive-javascript

The title of the question is really vague and I am sorry for that.

What want to do is something like this (many third party libraries do that)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

I want to apply a function like `datepicker()` to a textbox. What the function does is not important, but how it is being applied like above is what I am trying to find out how to do.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to know how to bind a function to an HTML element outside of the inline event-handling attributes (`onclick`, `onfocus`, `onchange` et cetera)? Or how to chain function-calls using methods (the difference between `document.getElementById('elem').getAttribute()` and `madeUpFunctionToGetAttributeFrom(document.getElementById('elem'))`)?

Comment: Sounds like you want to know how to make a jQuery plugin.  http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: "What the function does is not important" - I dare to guess it is.

Comment: @brad, seems like that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @georg ha! yes it is important to me what the function does. Just to fill you in, I want to run a validation on the content of the textbox. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($){
   $.fn.datepicker=function(){
      // do whatever you wanna do
      return this;
   }; 
})(jQuery);
```

allows you to do

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```